# Is there a way to figure out the limiting or asymptotic behavior of the difference function?

Tags: limits, asymptotics

Suppose I have a known real-valued function $f(x)$ and I'm interested in finding the asymptotic behavior for $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$. Is there a way to do this in general? For example, if $f(x)$ is a polynomial, then $g(x)$ is asymptotically equal to a polynomial as well, but of degree 1 less than $f$. But I'm not sure how to solve this problem for any arbitrary function $f$.

The precise problem I'm trying to solve has $f(x)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{p(x)}$ where $p(x)$ is a polynomial. For simplicity I started with $p(x)=x$, but I couldn't figure out how to find asymptotic behavior of $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{x}-\displaystyle\frac{e^{\sqrt{x-1}}}{x-1}$. I know the limit of this difference is infinite, but what would be its asymptotic behavior be like?

What would be a way to approach such a problem? I'd appreciate any hints or insights. Thanks! I should mention that I'm using the term 'asymptotically equal' here in the usual sense-$f$ and $g$ are asymptotically equal if the limit of their quotient is a constant as $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: If $p$ is an $n$th degree polynomial with leading coefficient unity, then $g \sim \frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{x^n}\left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}-\frac{8n+1}{8x} \right)$ as $x \to \infty$. You can find this essentially by following Claude's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)=\displaystyle\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{x}-\displaystyle\frac{e^{\sqrt{x-1}}}{x-1}$$ Dividing by $e^{\sqrt{x}}$ gives
$$\frac {g(x)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}}=\frac1x-\frac 1{x-1}e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}}}$$ Now, using Taylor
$$e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}}}=1-\frac 1{2x^{1/2}}+\frac 1{8x}-\frac 7{48x^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ and then
$$\frac {g(x)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}}=\frac 1{2 x^{\frac 32}}-\frac 9{8x^2}+\cdots$$ Computing for $x=10^4$
$$g(10^4)=\frac{e^{100}}{10000}-\frac{e^{3 \sqrt{1111}}}{9999}=1.3140\times 10^{37}$$ while the truncated series gives
$$g(10^4)\sim\frac{391 e^{100}}{800000000}=1.3138\times 10^{37}$$

**Edit**

Use the same approach for polynomials. For example $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ would give

$$\frac {g(x)}{e^{\sqrt{x}}}=\frac 1{2 x^{\frac 52}}-\frac {17}{8x^3}+\cdots$$ Considering only the first term of the expansion, you can conjecture that, if $n$ is the degree of the polynomial, then ....